# Make other branches auto rebase to current branch whenever I commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say I have a git tree like this:

[image]

Whenever I make a new commit on master branch, I have to do `git rebase master branch-x` to all other branches to maintain this structure. Is there anyway to automate this process? Especially, can I just `git commit some-magic-parameter` on master branch then see git rebasing other branches to new tip of master branch that I just commit?

Comment: Well, there certainly isn't `some-magic-parameter` but this is something you can easily accomplish writing a shell script. You could name it `git-commit-and-rebase`; as long as the script is in your path, git will find it and offer it for autocompletion.

Comment: Alternatively you could write a `post-commit` hook.

Comment: You can run multiple Git commands together using [aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced). This is in fact another kind of shell-scripting.